# TypeScript Generics type '{ result: true }' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

Attempting to use generic types but I can't seem to get it to work, though I'm sure it's something simple. Here's a basic example

```
// some module
type TMainResponse<T> = {
  data: T;
};

interface Foo {
  func<T>(): Promise<TMainResponse<T>>;
}

// local module
type TLocalResponse = {
  result: boolean;
};

const obj: Foo = {
  async func<TLocalResponse>() {
    return {
      data: {
        result: true
      }
    };
  }
};

(async function () {
  await obj.func();
});
```

The result of which is

```
Type 'Promise<{ data: { result: boolean; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<TMainResponse<T>>'.
    Type '{ data: { result: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'TMainResponse<T>'.
      Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
        Type '{ result: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.

16   async func<TLocalResponse>() {
           ~~~~

  src/test.ts:7:3
    7   func<T>(): Promise<TMainResponse<T>>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'func' which is declared here on type 'Foo'
```

Am I doing something wrong, or did I just misunderstand the usage of generics?

Comment: This isn't doing what you expect it to do. `async func<TLocalResponse>()  {}` will only assign a different name to `T` and doesn't refer to the type `TLocalResponse`. With definition `func<T>(): Promise<TMainResponse<T>>` youll need to specify what needs to be done when the user calls it with `func<string>()` or `func<number>()` for example (you'll need to actually define a generic `func<T>()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong, or did I just misunderstand the usage of generics?

This interface is at least a bit atypical:

```
interface Foo {
  func<T>(): Promise<TMainResponse<T>>;
}
```

The `Foo` has no type argument, but `<T>` is used in two places within the body. To be honest I'm not really sure how that's *supposed* to work (there's no compile error so it's likely working by design -- would be interested if someone can weigh in here) but if you change the interface to hold the type argument:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  func(): Promise<TMainResponse<T>>;
}
```

And the usage accordingly:

```
const obj: Foo<TLocalResponse> = {
  async func() {
    return {
      data: {
        result: true
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Then [the whole thing works fine](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0A%2F%2F%20some%20module%0D%0Atype%20TMainResponse%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20func()%3A%20Promise%3CTMainResponse%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20local%20module%0D%0Atype%20TLocalResponse%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20result%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%3A%20Foo%3CTLocalResponse%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20async%20func()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A(async%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20await%20obj.func()%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B).